# Open context menu on table row right click

Tags: antd

Is it possible to have the Dropdown Context Menu work for the whole Table row? We can render the Dropdown using the cell render method, but that way it doesn't cover the whole table cell because of cell padding. Thus the user has to precisely click the displayed text, instead of the whole cell.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the context menu you can use `Dropdown` or `Popover` components with some css customization, but the problem is the popup menu doesn't appear next to mouse pointer, it appears relatively to a wrapped element. You can check it **[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/n90579l9pm)** what I ment above.

I have made a custom Popup component. It looks for me some how ugly but anyway it works fine. **[You can check it here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rm23kroqyo)**.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! Much appreciated.

Comment: I changed the component type to  React Hooks function component and updated the dependencies. I kept the original code with comments at the bottom

Comment: @AliAlAmine Do you have a link to your solution?

Answer (score 3):

> For the context menu you can use `Dropdown` or `Popover` components with some css customization, but the problem is the popup menu doesn't appear next to mouse pointer, it appears relatively to a wrapped element. You can check it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/n90579l9pm) what I ment above.

It seems antd has already fixed the popup position issue of `Dropdown` component.